# How do I use :: when pattern matching in OCaml

Tags: list, functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

```
let rec (l:int list) f int list =
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | hd::tl -> 2+tl
```

I want to know is `hd` the first element and then `tl` is the second element because when i do this I keep getting an error, if `tl` is not the second element how would i access the second element an in depth explanation of `hd::tl` would be highly appreciated thank you

Comment: the second element is `b` in the expression `a::b::rest`

Comment: `hd` is the *head* and `tl` is the *tail* - which is the rest of the list, and is a list itself. It's not an element.

Comment: What error are you getting? What don't you understand about the error message?

Comment: How can I access the head of the other lists and the lists to come?

Comment: @timmydongy Recursively!

Answer (score 7):

No `tl` is not the second element, it is the rest of the list and it has type `'a list`. Here `hd` and `tl` are just variable names that you choose to bind to the first element of a list, and to the rest of the list (i.e., to a list that contains all elements except the first one). You can choose other names, e.g., `fst::rest`. Getting the second element, in that case would be as easy as `fst::snd::rest` (or `x::y::rest` - again the name doesn't matter).

What you're trying to use is called pattern matching. It is a feature of some languages, that provides a mechanism to easily deconstruct compound data structures. The idea is that if you're deconstructing data structures the same way as you're constructing them, e.g,

```
let xs = [1;2;3;4]
```

and here is the deconstructing

```
let [x1;x2;x3;x4] = xs
```

In fact, `[x;y;...;z]` is a syntactic sugar for a more basic syntax `x :: y:: ... :: z :: []`, so another way to construct the `[1;2;3;4]` list is to use the following construct: `1::2::3::4::[]`. The same works in the opposite direction, e.g.,

```
 let x1::x2::x3::x4::[] = xs
```

Now we are ready to the next step, what if the structure on the right doesn't match the structure on the left, e.g.,

```
 let [x;y;z] = [1;2]
```

or

```
 let x::y::z::[] = 1::2::[]
```

In that case, the matching will fail. In our case in runtime. To prevent this, and to allow programmers to handle all possible configuration of their data structures OCaml provides the `match` construct in which you specify multiple variants of the value structure, and the first one that matches is chosen, e.g.,

```
let orcish_length xs = match xs with
  | [] -> 0
  | x :: [] -> 1
  | x :: y :: [] -> 2
  | x :: y :: z :: [] -> 3
```

The function above anticipates only lists that have up to three elements (because Orcs can't count beyond three). But we can. For this we will use the following feature -- if the last element of the list pattern is not `[]` (that is matches only and only with the empty list, and designates the end-of-list), but anything else (i.e., a variable), then this variable will be bound to all elements, e.g.,

```
let rec elvish_length xs = match xs with
  | [] -> 0
  | x :: [] -> 1
  | x :: y :: [] -> 2
  | x :: y :: z :: [] -> 3
  | x :: y :: z :: leftovers -> 3 + elvish_length leftovers
```

So now, we anticipate all possible list patterns. However, the function is now overcomplicated (because Elves are complicating). Now, let's finally derive a normal, human readable, length function,

```
  let rec length xs = match xs with
    | [] -> 0
    | x :: xs -> 1 + length xs
```

As an exercise, try to prove to yourself that this function anticipates all possible lists.

Answer (score 4):

`::` is read `cons` and is an infix version of `List.cons`. In a functional language like Ocaml, list is a linked list where i.e.`[e1; e2; e3; e4]` can be reduced to something like this:

```
  cons(::)
 /     \
e1      cons(::)
        /     \
      e2      cons(::)
              /     \
             e3     cons(::)
                    /     \
                   e4      [ ]
```

Basically, any list can be reduced to a tree of recursive `cons` expressions, which makes recursion so useful in Ocaml or similar functional languages. At each level, you can reduce a list to its `head` and its `tail`, where tail is the list minus its head and can be reduced further until `last :: []`. So with the above example, you can recursively reduce the list until you find the last element by pattern-matching:

```
let find_last li =
  match li with
  | [] -> None                     (* no element *)
  | [last] -> Some last            (* found last *)
  | head :: tail -> find_last tail (* keep finding *)
;;
```

Note that `[last]` can be replaced with `last::[]` and `head::tail` with `List.cons head tail`. **What is important is at any point a list can always be reduced to `head :: tail`, where `head` is the first element and `tail` is the list without `head`**.

Pattern-matching is useful in matching the "shape" or state of the reducing list.

Comment: Great ASCII graphics!